# Creating a dynamic checkerboard, even numbers causing problems

Tags: java, javafx

My homework challenge is to make a checkerboard using JavaFX based on the size the user inputs from a JOptionPane. I've done this and works perfectly only with odd numbers, how can I fix this so it works for both odd and evens correctly?

I'm assuming it's an issue with how I'm polling the color to use since with even numbers each row would be identical.

```
    Color[] colors = {Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE};
    int nextColor = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
            nextColor = (nextColor == 0) ? 1 : 0;
            Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
            rec.setWidth(50);
            rec.setHeight(50);
            rec.setFill(colors[nextColor]);
            GridPane.setRowIndex(rec, row);
            GridPane.setColumnIndex(rec, col);
            grid.getChildren().addAll(rec);
        }
    }
```

odd numbers

[image]

even numbers

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going through the board filling the fields with alternating colors, a even number of columns will result in the last field being colored with a different color than the first field in the row and thus the first field in the next row will have the same color than the field directly above.

To fix this you can simply add the column and row numbers and take the remainder of the division by 2 to determine the color:

```
Color[] colors = {Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK};

for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
        int nextColor = (row + col) % 2;
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
        rec.setWidth(50);
        rec.setHeight(50);
        rec.setFill(colors[nextColor]);
        GridPane.setRowIndex(rec, row);
        GridPane.setColumnIndex(rec, col);
        grid.getChildren().addAll(rec);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't think of doing a remainder method.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant than what muzzlator proposes would be to set color by position alone, without storing some current alternate color. This is error-prone as you see.

Simply go with `int color = (row + col) % 2;`.